# HTML Agility Pack will not reference in W8 Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, html-agility-pack

I am trying to follow this tutorial using the HTML Agility Pack.
http://www.tareqateik.com/html-agility-pack%E2%80%93windows-phone-8#.VKl65ivF9a1

**In my application I installed the HTML Agility Pack, but I am getting this following error:**

"The type or namespace name 'HTMLAgilityPack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

**This error comes up in these two places:**

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

and 

HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
```

When I look under my references there is no reference to the pack, when I look at the sample code for the tutorial I find that he does have it referenced.

Can anyone tell me how to reference the HTMLAgilityPack?

Thank you

Comment: Did you install that nuget package to the right project within your solution?

Comment: Yeah I only have one project in this solution.

Comment: Did you install it on the solution or on that single project?

Comment: I installed it to the project not the solution. Is it supposed to be installed on the solution instead?

Comment: The article suggests the solution, but that's irrelevant in this case as you would just select the project(s). Have you already tried re-installing it?

Comment: Yeah I have tried that a few times. But I am still not getting anything in the references. Is it supposed to automatically reference itself under References?

Comment: Yep, it adds a packages directory in the file system, puts the dll in and references it. You could look for the dll and add the reference yourself but that's not how it's supposed to be... ;)

Comment: And how would I find the dll and where would I have to put it?

Comment: Right-click on your solution or project. Choose _open in explorer_. There'll be the _packages_-folder with the dll in it. You can leave it there and just add it to your project via the usual _add reference_ dialogue.

Comment: Okay I looked, but I do not have those files for some reason. I looked at the source code from the tutorial and I found where they stored the files under Bin->Debug

Do I need all of these? 

HtmlAgilityPack.dll
HtmlAgilityPack.pdb
HtmlAgilityPack.xml

If so could I just copy these into my own project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. There must be something wrong with the HTMLAgilityPack 1.4.9 version. I went ahead and installed HTMLAgilityPack 1.4.6, and that automatically added in all the correct references. If someone can confirm that 1.4.9 is not working for them as well that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could open your project file (the `YourProjectName.csproj`) with a text editor like notepad and look for that dll.

Somewhere must be a reference to the dll like the follwing entry:

```
<Reference Include="HtmlAgilityPack">
  <HintPath>..\packages\HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.9\lib\Net45\HtmlAgilityPack.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The path may vary, but an entry like that must be in your `csproj`, otherwise the dll wouldn't be copied to your bin folder.

Comment: This reference does not exist in my .csproj file. All the other references exist, but there is not one that points to the HtmlAgilityPack. Are you suggesting that I add this to this file?

Comment: Strange... Using the add reference dialog has the same effect. No need to edit the csproj manually.